# What does it mean to have double `var=` in one line in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm reading [this line](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/14/alpine/docker-entrypoint.sh#L186) from PostgreSQL's docker image repo.

```
PGHOST= PGHOSTADDR= "${query_runner[@]}" "$@"
```

I'm so confused why it has two `var=` pattern in one line. I can understand that `${query_runner[@]}` will gives the output of executing the command represented by `query_runner`, but which variable should this output be assigned to? Also, what does it mean by `$@` in this case?

Comment: `var=` is equivalent to `var=''`

Comment: `var= somecommand` does not change `var` except temporarily _while `somecommand` is running_. It is **not** how one saves `somecommand`'s output into a variable.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks! But still I'm confused how to interpret `PGHOST= PGHOSTADDR= "${query_runner[@]}" "$@"`. Does it mean that when `query_runner[@]` is running, `PGHOSTADDR` is temporarily changed (to what)? But how it has something to do with `PGHOST`?

Comment: @IsaKyodo, both `PGHOST` and `PGHOSTADDR` are temporarily changed to contain empty strings for the duration of `query_runner`'s execution.

Comment: @IsaKyodo, ...presumably, this is to prevent environment variables from overriding whatever configuration is set via dotfiles / defaults / etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks so much, I'm so much clearer now. One last question -- since this line has a `"$@"` at the very end, should I interpret it as:
1. run `query_runner`;
2. run what is in `$@`;
3. When running 1 and 2, set `PGHOST` and `PGHOSTADDR` to empty strings.
Do you think this is correct?

Comment: @IsaKyodo, `"$@"` (which is an array consisting of the arguments to the current script/function/etc) is extra arguments to pass to whatever command is constructed from the contents of the array `"${query_runner[@]}"`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, ahh. I see, so I should interprete `"${query_runner[@]}" "$@"` as one execution. Thanks so much!